# Vector of logicals based on row membership

Tags: r

thank you for your patience.

I am dealing with a large dataset detailing patients and medications.

Medications are hard to code, as they are (usually) meaningless unless matched with doses.

I have a dataframe with vectors (Drug1, Drug2..... Drug 16) where individual patients are represented by rows.
The vectors are actually factors, with 100s of possible levels (all the drugs the patient could be on).

All I want to do is produce a vector of logicals (TTTTFFFFTTT......) that I could then cbind into a dataframe which will tell me whether a patient is or is not on a particular, drug.

I could then use particularly important drugs' presence or absence as categorical covariates in a model.

I've tried grep, to search along the rows, and I can generate a vector of identifiers, but I cannot seem to generate the vector of logicals.

I realise I'm doing something simply wrong.

```
names(drugindex)
 [1] "book.MRN" "DRUG1"    "DRUG2"    "DRUG3"    "DRUG4"    "DRUG5"  
 [7] "DRUG6"    "DRUG7"    "DRUG8"    "DRUG9"    "DRUG10"   "DRUG11"  
[13] "DRUG12"   "DRUG13"   "DRUG14"   "DRUG15"   "DRUG16"  

> truvec<-drugindex$book.MRN[as.vector(unlist(apply(drugindex[,2:17], 2, grep, pattern="Lamotrigine")))]
> truvec
truvec
[1] 0024633  0008291  0008469  0030599  0027667
37 Levels: 0008291  0008469  0010188  0014217  0014439  0015822  ... 0034262

> head(drugindex)
   book.MRN       DRUG1        DRUG2          DRUG3        DRUG4        DRUG5
4  0008291  Venlafaxine Procyclidine  Flunitrazepam Amisulpiride    Clozapine
31 0008469  Venlafaxine  Mirtazapine        Lithium   Olanzapine   Metoprolol
3  0010188   Flurazepam    Valproate     Olanzapine  Mirtazapine Esomeprazole
13 0014217      Aspirin     Ramipril Zuclopenthixol    Lorazepam  Haloperidol
15 0014439    Zopiclone     Diazepam    Haloperidol  Paracetamol         <NA>
5  0015822   Olanzapine  Venlafaxine        Lithium  Haloperidol   Alprazolam
         DRUG6      DRUG7      DRUG8      DRUG9          DRUG10 DRUG11 DRUG12
4  Lamotrigine Alprazolam    Lithium Alprazolam            <NA>   <NA>   <NA>
31 Lamotrigine   Ramipril Alprazolam   Zolpidem Trifluoperazine   <NA>   <NA>
3  Paracetamol Alprazolam Citalopram       <NA>            <NA>   <NA>   <NA>
13        <NA>       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>            <NA>   <NA>   <NA>
15        <NA>       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>            <NA>   <NA>   <NA>
5         <NA>       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>            <NA>   <NA>   <NA>
   DRUG13 DRUG14 DRUG15 DRUG16
4    <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>
31   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>
3    <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>
13   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>
15   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>
5    <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>
```

And what I want is a vector of logicals for  each drug, saying whether that patient is on it

Thank you all for your time.

Ross Dunne MRCPsych

"Te occidere possunt sed te edere ne possunt, nefas est".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You were close with your `apply` attempt, but `MARGIN=2` applies the function over columns, not rows.  Also, `grep` returns the *locations* of the matches; you want `grepl`, which returns a logical vector.  Try this:

```
apply(x[,-1], 1, function(x) any(grepl("Aspirin",x)))
```

You could also use `%in%`, which you may find more intuitive:

```
apply(x[,-1], 1, "%in%", x="Aspirin")
```

Comment: A tricky vectorised approach is `rowSums(x[, -1] == "Asprin") > 0`

Comment: @hadley: you need `na.rm=TRUE` else you only receive `NA` in the OP's case.

Answer (score 4):

First, a comment on data structure. You have data in what some call a "wide" format, with a single row per patient and multiple columns for the drugs. It is usually the case that the "long" format, with reapeated rows per patient and a single column for drugs is more amenable to data manipulation. To reshape your data from wide to long and vice versa, take a look at the reshape package.  In this case, you would have something like:

```
library(reshape)
dnow <- melt(drugindex, id.var='book.MRN')
subset(dnow, value=='Lamotrigine')
```

Much cleaner, and obvious, code, if I may say so ...

Edit: If you need the old structure back you can use `cast`:

```
cast(subset(dnow, value=='Lamotrigine'),  book.MRN ~ value)
```

as suggested by @jonw in the comments.

Comment: A long format I think makes sense for repeated measurements (typically over time).  In this case, however, wide format makes a lot of sense because all you're talking about a single observation on a person and you're just recording what drugs they're taking.

Comment: Don't you mean `subset(dnow, value=='Lamotrigine')` (the variable column has levels `"DRUG1", "DRUG2", ...` etc)

Comment: @Dason. The "drug" dimension is not ordered, but this is irrelevant. What might be relevant for data storage purposes is the number of individual level vs drug level information. Too many individual specific variables and the data size grows ... fast. On the other hand, if you created N 'Drug' variables and suddenly someone takes 'N+1' drugs, you would have to create a new column. In this case, though, there is only one individual level variable (the ID).

Comment: This is very useful. After the above code, `cast(dnow, value~book.MRN)` is a nice answer to his question in matrix format.

Comment: Thanks guys for the great answers. This *is* in wide format, but it will be merged into a long format dataframe (therefore its rows will be repeated) for repeated observations on the patient, and repeated physiological observation within the patient, at separate treatment administrations, and within administrations, at separate timepoints. I'm going to have some fun modelling it! But it was really important to get this bit right! Thanks again

Comment: @rosser: please "accept" the most helpful answer for this and your other 3 questions.